# PHP good simple way to split the session variables into groups of values?

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array, serialization

I want to save part of the session into a big text field in a database table, after serializing it. Currently putting the session variables into an array seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a better way to define exactly which data is saved. I don't really want to end up with like a 4D array at some point, if I need to split up the session into multiple groups at the same time while also having sets of data stored as normal array in it.

For example if I want to save $_SESSION["client_gender"] to the db, but not all the other session stuff like user login status. I put the client set of data into an array, so that I can serialize and save only the client array: $_SESSION["clients"]["client_gender"].

```
$_SESSION["clients"]["group_1"]["client_gender"] = $_POST["client_gender"]; //some input from the user

function save_client(){
global $db;

if(isset($_SESSION["client_id"]) && $_SESSION["clients"]){
    $clients = serialize($_SESSION["clients"]);
    $query = "UPDATE clients SET clients = '{$clients}' WHERE id = {$_SESSION["client_id"]}"; //I know it's a bit confusing that a column has the same name as the table
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
}

// sometimes later when we want to use that client gender
function load_client(){
if(isset($_SESSION["client_id"])){
    $client = find_client_by_id($_SESSION["client_id"]); //just returns one row with a specific id from the clients table
    $_SESSION["clients"] = unserialize($client["clients"]);
}
}
echo $_SESSION["clients"]["group_1"]["client_gender"];
```

Is there another way to tag certain data as 'clients' and others as 'group_1', that may or may not overlap? They also need to be able to go in and out of a database as a group, without having to specifically insert each value in the DB and back to the session.

Comment: The session is stored in an array. You are free to do whatever you like with the data, within the confines of the array structure. On a more urgent note, your database code is outdated and leaves you open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I use mysqli_real_escape_string() on any text that goes into a query that a user inputs, if that's what you mean. Or is there something more I should do in the query code itself?